# Recursive search not returning parents

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a pipe in angular that needs to recursively do a search on a recursive object

The code below will return all the parents if you search for any child
so when searching 'grand child 1' it will return all of its parents as well

But when you search any parent, it will not return its children
So searching 'option 1' only returns 'option 1'

this is how my object looks like

```
options = [
  {
    key: "1",
    displayText: "option 1",
    group: [
      {
        key: "2",
        displayText: "child 1",
        group: [],
      },
      {
        key: "3",
        displayText: "child 2",
        group: [
          {
            key: "4",
            displayText: "grand child 1",
            group: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

```js
options.filter((option) => this.searchRecursive(option, searchText));

private searchRecursive(
  option: ISelectComponent,
  searchText: string
): boolean {
  const valueMatch = option.displayText.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);

  if (valueMatch) {
    return true;
  }

  if (option.group && option.group.length) {
    return option.group.some((child) =>
      this.searchRecursive(child, searchText)
    );
  }

  return false;
}
```

how would can I fix this issue, I suspect using the .filter might not be the answer here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `options` is an array of a single element, if the recursive function returns true, it'll return that element. If you want an exhaustive list of every matching object you need to recursively gather the objects that match the criteria.